# "org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed" in rare situations

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

I have the following code in Spring:

```java
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<SchedulingReportData> getSchedulingReport(String startDate, String endDate, boolean includeArchivedShipments) {
    requireNonNull(startDate);
    requireNonNull(endDate);

    Timestamp start = dateConvert.decodeToTimestamp(startDate);
    Timestamp end = dateConvert.decodeToTimestamp(endDate);

    List resultList = entityManager.createNativeQuery(GET_SCHEDULING_REPORT)
            .setParameter("startDate", start)
            .setParameter("endDate", end)
            .setParameter("includeArchivedShipments", includeArchivedShipments)
            .getResultList();

    return reportLoaderDelegate.buildSchedulingReportData(resultList);
}
```

In rare situations, when executing this method I get the following exception:

```java
org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.errorIfClosed(AbstractSessionImpl.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.setFlushMode(SessionImpl.java:1478)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$SessionTransactionData.resetSessionState(HibernateJpaDialect.java:361)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.cleanupTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:227)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCleanupAfterCompletion(JpaTransactionManager.java:594)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.cleanupAfterCompletion(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:811)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:504)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    at com.nap.shipment.delegate.ReportDelegate$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$754b3a3d.getSchedulingReport(<generated>)
    at com.nap.shipment.controller.ReportController$16.run(ReportController.java:240)
    at com.nap.shipment.utils.controller.ApiResponse.call(ApiResponse.java:20)
    at com.nap.shipment.utils.controller.ApiResponse.call(ApiResponse.java:1)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManager$4.run(WebAsyncManager.java:317)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I don't know if it's related or not, but this only happens when I'm querying for a lot of data (i.e. thousands of rows) at once. I thought it could be something to due with timeouts when accessing the datasource, but I increased the timeout values and the problem still happens.

Comment: I see no way that problem could occur. Have you tried to upgrade a bit the version of `Spring` or `Hibernate` you are using ? It looks to me like an issue affecting one version.

Comment: `ReportDelegate$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$754b3a3d` looks suspicious. Also its a better practice to have `@Transactional` with the business logic instead of having it on the DAO

Comment: Is statement_timeout set in the database?

Comment: @MarcLeBihan The version of `Hibernate` we're using is the one included in the `Spring Boot Starter` library. We can't really afford to upgrade `Spring` right now as it would involve a drastic change in a lot of the code.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I'm not sure what that `EnhancerBySpringCGLIB` is. There's only one method calling that method I put the code for, and it's the method of a `Controller` class for an HTTP Endpoint. Not sure where else to put the `@Transactional`

Comment: @Jeremy nop, it's set to 0, so it's off.